# Spring 3.2 Security - Login with non-unique username and additional info

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The title tries to explain the scenario:

This customer has a login functionality that allows users with the same name but on different locations (stores).

At the login page the user informs userName, password and the required store.

Using Spring Security (with JPA) I created an UserDetailsService implementation but this interface always receive an userName (and the store was essential to differ from another users).

Giving this situation I have two questions:

1. **How do I inform the spring security about the additional field?** (store)
2. **How do I implement an UserDetailsService with this info?**

Is that even possible? I've been doing some research but the solutions weren't clear.
 Thank you guys, you are the best =D

Comment: Did you managed to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not all clear to me. Do you have a unique login for multiple stores? Then you don't need to give the store to your `UserDetailsService` implementation. I would simply load the user information using its `username` and if the users are not authorized for all the stores, you could use the `GrantedAuthority` to define where the users is authorized, e.g. `ROLE_STORE_ID1`, `ROLE_STORE_ID2`, etc.

If you have multiple stores where users are not shared, then you could simply create a configurable custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`, instantiate one per store and uses the correct instance depending on the store the user is accessing.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I mean, can exists two users with the same name but for different stores.

So at the login page the user must inform the associated store to differ from another users with the same name from other stores.

 That's why I need the store (additional field) to make the search on the database, if I didn't the query may return several registries, not a single one.

 How can I get the store information on the UserDetailsService?

Comment: *capiche*? don't expect more help from me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to insult you. It's just an expression we use here at work a lot. Really sorry.